# form submit onload short trick?

Tags: javascript

I've been researching this, but can't find a reason this doesn't work.  I'm passing form data on from one page directly to another by catching the form, rebuilding in the catcher and trying to submit to the new page when the catching page loads. I'm looking for a quick qay to do this, and I'm curious why the following won't work:

```
<body onload="document.forms['frm'].submit()">
<form action='EditCampaign.php' method='post' name='frm'>
<?php
foreach ($_POST as $a => $b) {
echo "<input type='hidden' name='".htmlentities($a)."' value='".htmlentities($b)."'>";
}
?>
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: Please provide a *complete* reduced test case.

Comment: You must have a problem somewhere else because this works.

Comment: It would be helpful if you told us what, if any, errors are reported on the JavaScript console too.

Comment: Why would you submit a form with no action on pageload, it would be an infinite loop where the page would just reload and reload and the form submit and submit, over and over.

Comment: OK - _complete_ code is
`    <body onload="document.forms['frm'].submit()">
         <form action='EditCampaign.php' method='post' name='frm'>
         <?php
         foreach ($_POST as $a => $b) {
             echo "<input type='hidden' name='".htmlentities($a)."'      value='".htmlentities($b)."'>";
         }
        ?>
        </form>
    </body>`

Comment: Try it more like this -> http://jsfiddle.net/Xqe5N/

Comment: That isn't the complete code. We don't know what the contents of `$_POST` are for your test. Don't show people PHP when you have a client-side problem. And again, what does the JavaScript error console say?

Comment: Sorry - I've been up too long.  The Javascript Console says: `Uncaught TypeError: Property 'submit' of object #<HTMLFormElement> is not a function PostNewtarget.php:5
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'submit' of null `

Comment: The **generated** code is as follows:
    `<body onload="document.forms['frm'].submit()">
<form action='EditCampaign.php' method='post' name='frm'>
<input type='hidden' name='embeddable' value='0'><input type='hidden' name='addcampaign' value='1'><input type='hidden' name='capid' value='112'><input type='hidden' name='name' value='Chrysler'><input type='hidden' name='ARtype' value='Video'><input type='hidden' name='expdate' value=''><input type='hidden' name='title' value=''><input type='hidden' name='author' value=''><input type='hidden' name='submit' value='Submit'></form>
</body>
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Property 'submit' of object`#<HTMLFormElement>` is not a function

One of your inputs has `name="submit"`. This is overwriting the `submit` method of the form with a reference to the `HTMLElementNode`.

If you want to submit it programatically, you need to get a new one from somewhere else.

```
document.createElement('form').submit.apply( document.forms.frm );
```

This won't work (and there is no way to do this) in old Internet Explorer.

---

That said, you should probably find a different approach to the problem anyway. The data is being submitted to your server, you shouldn't need to pass it through the client in order to pass it to a different part of the same server.

Even if you are really passing it to another server (`action='EditCampaign.php'` suggests you are not, however) then some kind of inter-server communication with an identification token in the query string and a `Location` header is probably a better idea.

Comment: THAT WAS IT!  Submit had to be created. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this, added `action="yourpageurlhere"`

```
  <body onload="document.forms['frm'].submit()">

    <form name="frm" id="frm" action="yourpageurlhere">
      <input blah blah blah...>
   </form>
</body>
```

instead of

```
  document.frm.submit()
```

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement.submit

Comment: Did you added `action="yourpageurlhere"` in your form

Comment: the action was actually in the original code -

Comment: I just edited the post to reflect the whole code

Comment: This piece of coding working fine.

Comment: there must be something wrong in my browser, then - it just stops for me. I thought the code was fine